# jQuery - drag element -unbind/biind of mousedown/up triggering other mousedown events

Tags: jquery

I have a vertical drag element `#navSY`. It works fine but has a small issue. Everytime  I do `mouseup` the mouse events for the rest of the page get triggered/untriggerered. For instance, the element just below the dragged element has its `mousedown` event triggered everytime I drop `#navSY` on to it (to be more precise `#navSY` always remains within that element - before and after the drag).

Also the unbind event causes my other plugins to behave wierdly i.e. click and mousedown are not getting recognized.

I believe that the error is because I am doing `jQuery(document).unbind();` I should be targeting the element `#navSY` and the particular event `mousedown`. I tried to understand the bind/unbind in jQuery but couldn't get much of it as I am newbee. Any help will be appreciated.

```
jQuery('#navSY').bind({
        mousedown: function() {
            jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
            if(e.pageY>220) {
                jQuery('#navSY').css({
                    top: e.pageY - 2,
                });
    ...do...
            }
            else {
                jQuery(document).unbind();
            }
            });
        },
        mouseup: function() {
            jQuery(document).unbind();
        }
    });
```

Comment: [**event.stopPropagation()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

Comment: Solves part of the issue of mousedown. But the unbind statement unbinds the other plugins event too... editing my question as I was not clear initially.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see the rest of your code, but maybe if you add something relating to the event.target, it could help:

```
$('#elementBelowTheDraggedElement').on('mousedown',function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);        

    if(target.is('#navSY')) {
        //'return' stops execution of this function
        return;
    } else {
        //do what you originally wanted that mousedown event to do
    }
});
```

This should make it so that if the mousedown event occurs on #navSY, the function for your element that is *underneath* #navSY does not execute (if all goes well).

To unbind only a specific function, maybe try:

```
jQuery('#navSY').bind({
    mousedown: function() {
                                    //name the function?
        jQuery(document).mousemove(function myFunction(e) {
        if(e.pageY>220) {
            jQuery('#navSY').css({
                top: e.pageY - 2,
            });
...do...
        }
        else {

                                      //unbind that specific function?
            jQuery(document).unbind('mousemove.myFunction');
                                     /***********/
        }
        });
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        jQuery(document).unbind();
    }
});
```

Comment: event.stopPropagation() as suggested by adeneo in comments takes care of element below. But the unbind is unbinding the events of my other plugins. Is there something wrong in myunbind comment... is it too global?

Comment: Yes, $(document).unbind() could potentially be too global, as at first glance, it appears that it may unbind all functions attached to the document (anonymous functions are, by default, all attached to the 'window' object, which I believe is a child of 'document' in the way jQuery looks at it).

Comment: I've updated my response.  Maybe that will allow you to only unbind a specific function, rather than unbinding ALL functions of the window object, which could be the issue.